# '&' character in a text automatically converted to '&amp;' in SQL server while passing via parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am passing a text value say 'Test 1 & 2' to stored procedure via parameter.

While SQL server runs the SP, the parameter value '&' is automatically converted '&amp'.

I am basically searching for the text passed against table. In my table, I have records saved with '&'.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: AFAIK, MSSQL doesn't do conversion like this.  Something might be doing the conversion before you call the stored procedure.  Where and how do you call the stored proc?

Answer (score 0):

Got into a similar issue used the below when using Stuff on sql server

The below query changes the & as '&amp'.

```
(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';'+ Name FROM TABLE
FOR XML PATH(''),1,1,'')
```

The below query changes the & as &.

```
(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ';'+ Name FROM TABLE
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

This has sorted out the issue. The issue occurs when you merge & with other columns by default it converts the value to '&amp'.